# Why does ' ' in str(range(0,10)) resolve to True?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running Python 2.7 and trying to figure out why the expression:

```
' ' in str(range(0,10))
```

resolves to `True`.

I am checking for the '**space**' character.

Comment: To get the list of numbers as strings try: `[str(i) for i in range(10)]`

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you so much, that is what I was trying to do.

Comment: You are welcome.  This is what we call the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  In the future, it is best to describe your question as what you want to accomplish, and then list what you have tried and why you are confused about the results you have achieved.  Also since, @zerkms was the one who prompted you to give the information needed to actually get this answer, please consider marking his answer as accepted if contains the information you need. Cheers.

Comment: The XY Problem was a really interesting and helpful read. Thanks, I will definitely keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `str(range(0,10))` evaluates to a

```
"[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
```

string that certainly contains a space. And digits, and square brackets, and commas.

As mentioned in the comments, if you need to generate a list of numbers formatted as strings you may [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[str(i) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Oh, OK thanks. I am new to coding and was trying to create the list of the numbers as strings. Thanks again, that solves it.